# Create a switch that changes the color palette of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I'm trying to create a switch/button/link that directly changes the color theme/colors/color palette on the website.

For example, let's say when it's night you would prefer having a dark background, or when it's daylight you'd prefer a bright background. It's kinda like the Dark Theme and White Theme in most iPhone Apps. There's also that "switching-thing" on most porn websites, so people won't see their reflection on their computer screen when they.. well you know.

I found solutions on here, but they don't work when a background-color has already been set up in CSS. I've tried everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eqdfs/

Here's the code I'm using but it's not working :

HTML

```
<body>
<a id="btn1">black</a><br/>
<a id="btn2">white</a><br/>
<a id="btn3">grey</a>
</body>
```

CSS

```
<style>
/*SWITCH*/
body.black {
background: #000000;
}

body.white {
background: #ffffff;
}

body.gray {
background: #C0C0C0;
}
</style>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('black');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('white');
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('gray');
});
</script>
```

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery so explain yourself a bit please.

Thank you for your time!

Here's a screenshot of what's happening for further help : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDkYf.png

EDIT: I found the solution. In order to work, I had to load the jQuery 1.7.2 in the head tag, like this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post your code so we can see. And why are you not using the code you provided in the jsFiddle-link?

Comment: I worked on the fiddle for me. Further, the `.class3` background image url is broken.

Comment: Yah the jsfiddle code seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: The image your using for `.class3` is broken. Do you want to use images or background colors?

Comment: We need the code here, since links tend to rot. If jsFiddle is down, your question without code doesn't make much sense. Remember, the question and answers are not just for you, they are for future visitors as well.

Comment: Alright, so I posted the code in my original post. Let me know! Thank you and sorry for the mess, I'm new here.

Comment: I posted a link to a screenshot if that can help...

Comment: Found the solution, posted it at the end of the OP. In case you want to know. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Will do. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body>
<a id="btn1">Noise BG</a><br/>
<a id="btn2">RVB BG</a><br/>
<a id="btn3">dunno BG</a>   
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('black');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('white');
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('gray');
});
```

CSS:

```
body.black {
 background: #000000;
}

body.white {
 background: #ffffff;
}

body.gray {
 background: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. But it doesn't work. I'm trying to put that on a Tumblr blog. Would that be the reason?

Comment: If the blog allows for adding custom HTML/CSS/JavaScript then it should work, I'm not familiar enough with it. Check out this article: http://www.problogtricks.com/2013/12/add-custom-css-javascript-code-to-tumblr-blog.html

Comment: Yes it does, it's the whole the point of Tumblr actually, you can custom the HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I posted the code I'm using in my original post. Thanks for the link.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work", the code is valid but I'd have to see it as a whole. Is your JavaScript located at the bottom of your page allowing all the DOM elements to load?

Comment: Well, when I click on the text that says "black" for example, nothing happens. The cursor even stays the text cursor... And nope, I put the JavaScript in the head tag within <script></script>, not at the end of the body tag.

Comment: Try adding `$( document ).ready(function() {` + your Javascript here + `});` to ensure the DOM has been completely loaded.

Comment: Would it be because I have to use a link to jQuery 1.7.2? Like on the JSFiddle.

Comment: Yep, it was indeed because I didn't load the jquery link in the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <body>
    <a id="btn1">Noise BG</a>
    <a id="btn2">RVB BG</a>
    <a id="btn3">dunno BG</a>

    <ul id="switcher">
  <li id="grayButton"></li>
  <li id="whiteButton"></li>
  <li id="blueButton"></li>
  <li id="yellowButton"></li>
</ul>

<h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>

<p>Try clicking on one of the colors above to change the colors on this page!</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:top-left;
}

body.class1 {
    background-image:url('http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~lotufo/Courses/ia-636-1995/alberto/proj5/html/pattern_Id.gif');
    color:yellow;
}

body.class2 {
    background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Pattern_square_16.png');
    color:red;
}

body.class3 {
    background-image:url('http://www.herbactive.com.br/catalog/view/theme/default/image/pattern/pattern-11.png');
    color:blue;
}


a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    background:#ffffff;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:2px 0;
}
body {
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
body.gray {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
body.white {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
body.blue {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
body.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}
p {
  margin: .5em 0;
}

#switcher {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#switcher li {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

#grayButton {
  background: gray;
}
#whiteButton {
  background: white;
}
#blueButton {
  background: blue;
}
#yellowButton {
  background: yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class1');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class2');
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class3');
});
$('#grayButton').click(switchGray);
$('#whiteButton').click(switchWhite);
$('#blueButton').click(switchBlue);
$('#yellowButton').click(switchYellow);

function switchGray() {
  $('body').attr('class', 'gray');
}

function switchWhite() {
  $('body').attr('class', 'white');
}

function switchBlue() {
  $('body').attr('class', 'blue');
}

function switchYellow() {
  $('body').attr('class', 'yellow');
}
```

Comment: please explain the answer